# bootgrid change checkbox into radiobutton

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, jquery-bootgrid

I'm using [jQuery-Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/) to create my tables. If I set `rowSelect=true` and `multiSelect=false`the checkbox can not be clicked (or checked).

I want to change the checkbox into a radiobutton if `rowSelect=true` and `multiSelect=false`. I don't know how to change this without editing the jquery.bootgrid.js file. Otherwise I don't know how to change this if I edit jquery.bootgrid.js.

The question is, how to :D